# Problema with permission Api level 23

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I happen following the example of google developers how to implement "dangerous permissions" for api 23 and above, I am following this simple code:

```
//Sino tenemos los permisos:
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Si anteriormente se pidieron los permisos y el usuario le dio a cancelar
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "El usuario ya denegó el permiso anteriormente y me fa falta");
    } else {
        // Si es la primera vez, el should nunca se ha producido con lo que es falso y lanzamos la peticion del permiso
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 69);
    }
}
```

All goes well, the first time we went, we go else for the system asks the user if we grant permission and here comes the problem, you never get that message so that I can cancel / accept. It is very rare because I have tested from an app made from scratch the same code and if it works but when I put it inside the app I'm doing is not working.

Comment: Can you show where this code is being executed? Is it possible you never reach this piece?

Comment: he problem was that it does not permit the AndroidManifest, beginner's mistake :(